# Cycle through all possible group cominations for highest value

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics, mathematical-optimization

I'm putting together a java applet to make a task faster and more efficient at work.

The user defines the size of three groups that a list of items will need to be split into. Each item in the list has a different value based on which of the three groups it is placed into. The applet needs to display which combination(s) have the highest total value.

Example:
A 2D array of integers with columns; item number, value in group 1, value in group 2, and value in group 3.

```
16   2   2   5
19   6   0   3
24   1   4   4
25   4   2   3
27   4   2   3
29   3   3   3
31   5   3   1
32   5   2   2
```

With this the user defines group 1 to have 3 slots, group 2 to have 3 slots, and group 3 to have 2 slots.

The applet should display, in no particular order, the following solutions

```
Group 1: 19, 31, 32
Group 2: 24, 27, 29
Group 3: 16, 25
OR
Group 1: 19, 27, 32
Group 2: 24, 29, 31
Group 3: 16, 25
OR
Group 1: 19, 31, 32
Group 2: 24, 25, 29
Group 3: 16, 27
OR
Group 1: 19, 25, 32
Group 2: 24, 29, 31
Group 3: 16, 27
```

I can manage a not-so-efficient way to run the array though all of the possible orders, but it would produce duplicate solutions (ie 16,25 and 25,16). I'm sure there is a way to sum up all the possible combinations without even shuffling the array. I just can't wrap my head around it at the moment. If any of you have a method for this, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: This isn't so much a java/arrays/applet question as it is an algorithms question.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. I couldn't think of the appropriate tag, so I took from the tag suggestions it provided.

Comment: This is a fairly interesting question. At first I thought it was a knapsack problem, but it's not because every element is the same size. It's a lot easier to solve with only two groups, but I'm not sure how to generalize to three...

Comment: It is a type of assignment problem. However, I think an assignment problem shall give only one solution.

Comment: Are there only 3 lists?

Comment: Abhishek Bansal, is there no way to adapt that method to store solutions that tie?

Comment: Do you really require to print all solution with maximum total value or finding just one is fine too?

Comment: Unfortunately, I really need all solutions. As long as we have a method that compares all solutions looking for the best though, we should be able to store results that tie the current best and wipe them if the result is beaten.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: a new approach using dynamic programming

---

(The old one:)

I think we can use a greedy approach. The idea is:

1. Find the largest value in the table. Put the corresponding item into the corresponding group.
2. Remove the corresponding row of the item from the table.
3. When a group is full, remove the corresponding column of the group.

To implement the above idea, we may use an array `used[]` to recognize whether an item is used (already put in to a group), three maximum-heaps to represent the three value columns in the table. The heap element is like  (value is key). Suppose the three heaps are `H[0]`, `H[1]`, and `H[2]`. The algorithm is like this:

```
Init bool array `used[n]` to all false 
Init heap array `H[3]`
Init int array `capacity[3]` to required group sizes
for(int i from 0 to n-1){
    int v = -1, heap_number, item_number;
    for(int j from 0 to 2){
        if(capacity[j] == 0){
            continue;
        }
        while(used[H[j].top().item_number]){
            H[j].pop();
        }
        if(H[j].top().value > v){
            v = H[j].top().value;
            heap_number = j;
            item_number = H[j].top().item_number;
        }
    }
    Assign Item item_number to Group heap_number
    used[item_number] = true;
    capacity[heap_number]--;
}
```

---

Here is my new approach, a dynamic programming approach:

- Suppose `f[i][j][k]` represents the solution for group 1, 2, and 3 each having i, j, and k slots left respectively. A solution is three lists, recording assignments from items to groups. Suppose `a = i + j + k`.
- State transition equation: `f[i][j][k] = max{f[i-1][j][k] + Item[a].value_1, f[i][j-1][k] + Item[a].value_2, f[i][j][k-1] + Item[a].value_3}`.
- Init state: `f[0][0][0] = 0`.
- Final answer: `f[group_1_size][group_2_size][group_3_size]`.

Comment: `1: 10 9 9; 2: 9 1 1, 3: 9 1 1`, slots: 1 1 1. So, in you algo we will have total score of 12, when we can easily fetch 19.

Comment: In it's current state, it would maximize group 1 and leave group 2 and 3 with whatever is left. As Serge pointed out, this could potentially result in a bad answer. However, what if I ran this method 6 times (1 for each different group order) and kept the best of the 6 attempts? This might be sufficient even if it's not particularly efficient, unless I'm missing a scenario where it would still produce a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think out a solution, but answering your question - about running through all possible sums - you could use recursion.

```
// @row - currently processed row
// @g1, g2, g3 - arrays with numbers of rows put in respective group
// @options - for results
// @rows - source array
void PROCESS_ROW(int row, int[] g1, int[] g2, int[] g3, int[][][][] options, rows) {
    if (row >= rows.length) {
        // Recursion ended, collecting generated distribution
        options[].push_back(new int[3][][]);
        options[last][0] = g1.clone();
        options[last][1] = g2.clone();
        options[last][2] = g3.clone();
        return;
    }
    // Trying to put row in each group consequently
    if (g1.length < g1_slots) {
        g1.push_back(row);
          PROCESS_ROW(row + 1, g1, g2, g3, options, rows);
        g1.pop_back();
    }
    if (g2.length < g2_slots) {
        g2.push_back(row);
          PROCESS_ROW(row + 1, g1, g2, g3, options, rows);
        g2.pop_back();
    }
    if (g3.length < g3_slots) {
        g3.push_back(row);
          PROCESS_ROW(row + 1, g1, g2, g3, options, rows);
        g3.pop_back();
    }
}

int[][] rows;
// .. fill
int[][][][] options;

PROCESS_ROW(0, new int[], new int[], new int[], options, rows);
// now options contains all possible groupings
```

Actually, this code isn't Java, so it needs to be adapted. Also, g1_slots etc. must also be passed to function as arguments, but it's details. The idea is understandable. Also, it's very possible to include stronger processing in first `if` part, calculating sums and storing highest one along with possible combinations. And clearing array each time higher sum is encountered.
And of course this solution implies that rows have numbers 0, 1, 2.., insead of 16, 19, 25... So, this aspect should be adjusted again, using `Map rows` instead of array. But as I said, it's details.